Anime TV show with a scene where vampires having a bloody fight till one of them dies
I remember watching an anime video about the vampire's bloody fight on some social network site like Facebook/Instagram. Here are the details:
Fight scene description :
There were two vampires (one male, other female) and one frightened girl who looked geekish/nerdish. Female one treats male one like he is her successor or student or maybe she made him vampire in the first place. 
Both vampire were having a bloody fight with each other with giving full percentage of there potential. They were able to decapitate each other repeatedly but not able to resurrect every time. Their vampire ability was very different from Hollywood; they were more of indestructible with no weakness as they were fighting in Colosseum/stadium like structure which most probably was open from above. 
They were even able to reconstruct their whole body just out of their head. Guy even pierced woman's breast with his head during the fight.
Fight ending:
They started fighting near the frightened girl and she might be shaking in terror. It looked like guy was protective to her and also he might be the protagonist of the show. Female vampire who looked like antagonist during the fight separated his head and his flying head come near her neck and suck out all her energy and somehow she was not able to resurrect this time and he regenerate his whole body.
Animation style:
It was similar to Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood in animation style but more bloody.
Language:
Japanese with English subbed 
Country:
Japan (most probably as it was anime)
Colour/Black and White:
For sure coloured.
Release/Broadcast year:
Most probably post 2000. 
Character looks:
Vampire girl had light colour hair (most probably white, yellow or golden) and might be wearing dress with white and red combination with maybe brown and maybe open shoulders with frills , guy had dark colour hair (brown or black) and have equal height to teh vampire girl, spectator girl was shorter in height compare to other two and might be wearing glasses and appears to be younger then other two.

It can be a anime movie but it gave me vibe of being a TV show.

My initial thought was Hellsing Ultimate, but I couldn't find any characters who fitted your description of the blonde woman.
My second thought is the Monogatari series, specifically Kizumonogatari Part 1. The character of Kiss Shot Acerola Orion Heart Under Blade (better known as Shinobu Oshino) is a vampire, and her appearance in this film somewhat resembles your description. She also participates in a bloody fight, though the ending doesn't match your description: her arms are severed but she is very much alive.
EDIT: Ankit himself has confirmed in the comments that the fight is actually from Kizumonogatari Part 3, so I was slightly off. The fight is between Kiss Shot and Koyomi Araragi, the central protagonist of the Monogatari franchise. The nerdy girl watching on is Tsubasa Hanekawa, a schoolfriend of Koyomi's.
The full fight can be viewed here (warning: NSFW, extremely violent):




I dig myself a bit too after the help from anime.se users and I got the answer, it's Kizumonogatari III: Reiketsu-hen  and this is the fight scene I was talking about NSFW https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NBUkzUmWHY , Anyway thanks and you might want to update your answer
